# Use a dynamic value in Mule where MEL is not supported

Tags: mule

I am using an SFTP connector as an outbound endpoint.

I require to be able to dynamically set the Authentication Identity File and Passphrase. This is because we are dynamically choosing where we send the file to.

It seems in the Mule version I am using (5.2) does not support the use of MEL in this particular field. It works for other fields, but not the authentication.

Is there a simple way to allow me to dynamically populate this field somehow?

I have considered both extending the SFTP component and making the getIdentityFile() method be processed via MEL, but this is an extreme solution I want to avoid if I can.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting this to work was a bit of a mission, but it is indeed doable.

The general steps is to use the `<service-overrides>` tag to override a specific component which eventually allows one to execute Java code which evaluates the identity file as a MEL expression.

The classes we are overriding are contained in the Mule SFTP component Github repository, here: https://github.com/muleforge/SFTP/tree/master/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/sftp

First, you need to use the appropriate service-override in your SFTP connector:

```
<sftp:connector name="SEND_SFTP">
    <service-overrides dispatcherFactory="customsftp.CustomSftpDispatcherFactory" />
</sftp:connector>
```

Then create the Java classes which allow you to implement the above logic:

```
public class CustomSftpDispatcherFactory extends SftpMessageDispatcherFactory {

    @Override
    public MessageDispatcher create(OutboundEndpoint endpoint) throws MuleException
    {   
        return new CustomSftpMessageDispatcher(endpoint);
    }
}
```

And next you update the `SftpMessageDispatcher` class. This class :

```
public class CustomSftpMessageDispatcher extends AbstractMessageDispatcher
{

    private SftpConnector connector;
    private SftpUtil sftpUtil;

    public CustomSftpMessageDispatcher(OutboundEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        super(endpoint);
        connector = (SftpConnector) endpoint.getConnector();
        sftpUtil = new CustomSftpUtil(endpoint);
    }

    protected void doDisconnect() throws Exception
    {
        // no op
    }

    protected void doDispose()
    {
        // no op
    }

    protected void doDispatch(MuleEvent event) throws Exception
    {
        String filename = buildFilename(event);
        InputStream inputStream = generateInputStream(event);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            logger.debug("Writing file to: " + endpoint.getEndpointURI() + " [" + filename + "]");
        }

        SftpClient client = null;
        boolean useTempDir = false;
        String transferFilename = null;

        try
        {
            String serviceName = (event.getFlowConstruct() == null)
                                 ? "UNKNOWN SERVICE"
                                 : event.getFlowConstruct().getName();
            SftpNotifier notifier = new SftpNotifier(connector, event.getMessage(), endpoint, serviceName);
            client = connector.createSftpClient(endpoint, notifier);
            String destDir = endpoint.getEndpointURI().getPath();

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
            {
                logger.debug("Connection setup successful, writing file.");
            }

            // Duplicate Handling
            filename = client.duplicateHandling(destDir, filename, sftpUtil.getDuplicateHandling());
            transferFilename = filename;

            useTempDir = sftpUtil.isUseTempDirOutbound();
            if (useTempDir)
            {
                // TODO move to a init-method like doConnect?
                // cd to tempDir and create it if it doesn't already exist
                sftpUtil.cwdToTempDirOnOutbound(client, destDir);

                // Add unique file-name (if configured) for use during transfer to
                // temp-dir
                boolean addUniqueSuffix = sftpUtil.isUseTempFileTimestampSuffix();
                if (addUniqueSuffix)
                {
                    transferFilename = sftpUtil.createUniqueSuffix(transferFilename);
                }
            }

            // send file over sftp
            // choose appropriate writing mode
            if (sftpUtil.getDuplicateHandling().equals(SftpConnector.PROPERTY_DUPLICATE_HANDLING_APPEND))
            {
                client.storeFile(transferFilename, inputStream, SftpClient.WriteMode.APPEND);
            }
            else
            {
                client.storeFile(transferFilename, inputStream);
            }

            if (useTempDir)
            {
                // Move the file to its final destination
                client.rename(transferFilename, destDir + "/" + filename);
            }

            logger.info("Successfully wrote file '" + filename + "' to " + endpoint.getEndpointURI());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Unexpected exception attempting to write file, message was: " + e.getMessage(), e);

            sftpUtil.setErrorOccurredOnInputStream(inputStream);

            if (useTempDir)
            {
                // Cleanup the remote temp dir from the not fullt completely
                // transferred file!
                String tempDir = sftpUtil.getTempDirOutbound();
                sftpUtil.cleanupTempDir(client, transferFilename, tempDir);
            }
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (client != null)
            {
                // If the connection fails, the client will be null, otherwise
                // disconnect.
                connector.releaseClient(endpoint, client);
            }

            inputStream.close();

        }

    }

    private InputStream generateInputStream(MuleEvent event)
    {
        Object data = event.getMessage().getPayload();
        // byte[], String, or InputStream payloads supported.

        byte[] buf;
        InputStream inputStream;

        if (data instanceof byte[])
        {
            buf = (byte[]) data;
            inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
        }
        else if (data instanceof InputStream)
        {
            inputStream = (InputStream) data;
        }
        else if (data instanceof String)
        {
            inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(((String) data).getBytes());
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Unexpected message type: java.io.InputStream, byte[], or String expected. Got "
                    + data.getClass().getName());
        }
        return inputStream;
    }

    private String buildFilename(MuleEvent event)
    {
        MuleMessage muleMessage = event.getMessage();
        String outPattern = (String) endpoint.getProperty(SftpConnector.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_PATTERN);
        if (outPattern == null)
        {
            outPattern = (String) muleMessage.getProperty(SftpConnector.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_PATTERN, connector.getOutputPattern());
        }
        String filename = connector.getFilenameParser().getFilename(muleMessage, outPattern);
        if (filename == null)
        {
            filename = (String) event.getMessage().findPropertyInAnyScope(SftpConnector.PROPERTY_FILENAME,
                                                                          null);
        }
        return filename;
    }

    protected MuleMessage doSend(MuleEvent event) throws Exception
    {
        doDispatch(event);
        return event.getMessage();
    }
}
```

The only important part of that class was in the constructor, constructing the custom SFTP util:

```
public class CustomSftpUtil extends SftpUtil {

    private SftpConnector connector;
    private MuleContext context;

    public CustomSftpUtil(ImmutableEndpoint endpoint) {
        super(endpoint);

        connector = (SftpConnector) endpoint.getConnector();
        context = endpoint.getMuleContext();

        handleIdentityFile();
        handlePassphrase();
    }

    private void handleIdentityFile() {
        String evaluatedExpression = evaluateMelExpression(connector.getIdentityFile());
        connector.setIdentityFile(evaluatedExpression);
    }

    private void handlePassphrase() {
        String evaluatedExpression = evaluateMelExpression(connector.getPassphrase());
        connector.setPassphrase(evaluatedExpression);
    }

    private String evaluateMelExpression(String melExpression) {        
        return context.getExpressionManager().evaluate(melExpression, RequestContext.getEvent()).toString();
    }
}
```

The only important part of this class is the evaluation of the identity file (and passphrase) as MEL expressions, which allows us to dynamically set the Identity file and Passphrase via a MEL expression.